# Query Param value is not set by Jersey

Tags: java, servlets, jersey

```
ServletContext servletContext = request.getServletContext();
rd = servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/rest/v1/code?param1=" + URLEncoder.encode(code, "UTF-8") + "&param2=" + value);
rd.forward(request, response);
```

When I directly invoke the uri "rest/v1/code" with param1 value as "dsk?text=sas" encoded input. I'm able to receive the param1 value in Jersey resource.

But dispatching via the above servlet resource, the query param values are set as null in Jersey resource.

This problem arises only when the param1 contains '?' as a part of input. Kindly help me resolve this problem.

```
@GET
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
public Response getResponse(@QueryParam("param1") String param1))
```

Note : Inside the jersey resource

String str = request.getQueryString(); gives me "text=sas";

the param1 value is not set, it is null

whereas request.getParameter("param1") gives me actual value ("dsk?text=sas")

Comment: I just tried your code with dsk?text=sas and it works for me. I used request.getSession(true).getServletContext() as its a method on session

Comment: Please show the Jersey resource method code.

Comment: request.getSession(true).getServletContext() was not helpful.. pls check note in the post

Comment: `request.getSession(true)` in a REST context makes not sense.